# Is there any way to get specific url after hitting a URL from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, windows, selenium

basically I need to call a URL(some auth based) from my VBA script. when i call it, it will open in browser with respective screen, after authenticating that page it will directing to other url in same page. i want to load that URL in my VBA code.
Can you please help me. which library i need to use in VBA. i tried normal hitting with shell() `Shell(chrome & " -url " & url)` but by this there is no control on browser to VBA. also i tried selenium. i am unable to locate the URL.
Dim driver As WebDriver

```
Set driver = New WebDriver
    driver.Start "chrome"
    driver.Get url
    driver.Wait 10000
    Url = driver.Url
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
```

Please suggest required

Comment: What does it mean to **hit** a URL?????

Comment: And, why is this tagged _shell_?

Comment: check out "[ask]" as well as how to create a [mcve]

Comment: I have updated my question please check